# Calling a Keras model on a TensorFlow tensor but keep weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In [Keras as a simplified interface to TensorFlow: tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) they describe how one can call a Keras model on a TensorFlow tensor.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=784))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# this works! 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = model(x)
```

They also say:

> Note: by calling a Keras model, your are reusing both its architecture and its weights. When you are calling a model on a tensor, you are creating new TF ops on top of the input tensor, and these ops are reusing the TF Variable instances already present in the model.

I interpret this as that the weights of the model will be the same in `y` as in model. However, for me it seems like the weights in the resulting Tensorflow node are reinitialized. A minimal example can be seen below:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# Create model with weight initialized to 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='ones',
                bias_initializer='zeros'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Save the weights 
model.save_weights('file')

# Create another identical model except with weight initialized to 0
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='zeros',
                 bias_initializer='zeros'))
model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
# Load the weight from the first model
model2.load_weights('file')
# Call model with Tensorflow tensor
v = tf.Variable([[1, ], ], dtype=tf.float32)
node = model2(v)
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(node), model2.predict(np.array([[1, ], ])))
# Prints (array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32))
```

### Why I want to do this:

I want to use a trained network in another minimization scheme were the network "punish" places in the search space that are not allowed. So if you have ideas not involving this specific approach, that is also very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found the answer. There are two problems in the example from the question.

### 1:

The first and most obvious was that I called the `tf.global_variables_intializer()` function which will re-initialize all variables in the session. Instead I should have called the `tf.variables_initializer(var_list)`  where `var_list` is a list of variables to initialize.

### 2:

The second problem was that Keras did not use the same session as the native Tensorflow objects. This meant that to be able to run the tensorflow object  `model2(v)` with my session `sess` it needed to be reinitialized. Again [Keras as a simplified interface to tensorflow: Tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) was able to help

> We should start by creating a TensorFlow session and registering it with Keras. This means that Keras will use the session we registered to initialize all variables that it creates internally.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
```

If we apply these changes to the example provided in my question we get the following code that does exactly what is expected from it.

```py
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
sess = tf.Session()
# Register session with Keras
K.set_session(sess)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='ones',
                bias_initializer='zeros'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.save_weights('test')

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='zeros',
                 bias_initializer='zeros'))
model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.load_weights('test')
v = tf.Variable([[1, ], ], dtype=tf.float32)
node = model2(v)
init = tf.variables_initializer([v, ])
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(node), model2.predict(np.array([[1, ], ])))
# prints: (array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32))
```

### Conclusion:

The lesson is that when mixing Tensorflow and Keras, make sure everything uses the same session.

Comment: What is wrong with using `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in your example?

Comment: @ImranRashid tf.global_variables_initializer() will re-initialize **all** variables including the weights in the Keras model that I wanted to keep untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this question, and answering it, it helped me! In addition to setting the same tf session in the Keras backend, it is also important to note that if you want to load a Keras model from a file, you need to run a global variable initializer op before you load the model.

```
sess = tf.Session()

# make sure keras has the same session as this code
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

# Do this BEFORE loading a keras model
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)


model = models.load_model('path/to/your/model.h5')
```

Comment: Nice to hear that my struggles helped someone. It was actually the process of formulating the question that got me on the right track to solving the issue.